# When is it appropriate to use zero_grad()?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor, autograd

I have 2 neural networks discriminator and the generator.So when I do lossgenerator.backward() the gradients are calculated over the tensors of the discriminator too as the tensors from the discriminators are fed to the generator and vice versa.
Now my question is that if I do-

```
lossDiscriminator.backward(retain_graph=True)
lossgenerator.backward()
```

will the gradients of the tensors from the discriminator will be calculated twice? or should I do
Discriminator.zero_grad() and Generator.zero_grad() before I call lossgenerator.backward()?

Comment: Am I mistaken in that the generator should be fed into the discriminator? Not the other way around. Gradients in pytorch accumulate, so you should zero grad any which you wish to recalculate (unless accumulation is your goal, of course).

Comment: The tensors of the fake images from the discriminator are fed to the generator to calculate the loss of the generator